# Traverse specific parts of AST Tree

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I have dump the AST Tree of a simple C++ codes.
[image]

Is it possible to only visit the nodes selected and ignore everything else including the children using libTooling or ASTMatchers?

Answer (score 1):

- Find any `stmt` (or a subclass of statements good for you)
- Add a condition that they `hasParent`, probably a `CompundStmt` based on your example.
- Again based on your example, you probably want to enforce that the `CompundStmt` `hasParent`, which is a `FunctionDecl`

See the [AST matchers reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html) for details.